# How to remove JWT from DB after cookie is deleted by browser

Tags: database, security, jwt, refresh-token

I am using Express and Node.js for my API and another Auth Server. Currently, when a user logs in, a refresh token is sent back in an Http cookie and an access token is sent back and stored in localStorage. I have set it up this way because it allows for the user to have multiple sessions in other tabs/browsers etc. When a user logins, if they hit 'Remember Me' an item in LS is stored that says to login next time, and on app start it checks that and calls the API for login if it's true. It will then send the Access Token stored in LS and the cookie as well. When a user first logins it will get a refresh and store it in the Database in an array of tokens (to let multiple sessions work w/o overriding tokens), and then every subsequent request will check the cookie token vs the one in the DB. This all works fine UNTIL the cookie is deleted. Once the user closes the browser or it removes the cookie manually, the one in the DB stays there and overtime will just rack up tokens.

So my question is: How do I remove the token in the DB once the cookie is deleted/removed?

Comment: I suggest not even storing the tokens in your database in the first place.  One of the whole points of using JWT is to avoid having _stateful_ sessions.  Instead, JWT allow the server to basically push the session state out to the user.  Please read about using JWT for more information.

Comment: You need a plain old session with plain session ids. That will be simpler, you will already find well known implementations, and it will be significantly more secure.